# want to Write a Stored Procedure in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, parameters, find-in-set

i have 3 tables e.g A, B, C
want to select from A then Update B and Insert into C
i hv written SP like This.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE ABC( IN id int )
BEGIN       
        SELECT * FROM A WHERE FIND_IN_SET(LEFT(A.id,10),id);
        UPDATE B
        SET e.g=e.g     WHERE e.g
        INSERT INTO B (....) SELECT .,.,.,.  
        FROM         ; 
END //
```

**The problem is i hav variable amount of id's to pass on this Sp, can be min1 and max (maybe 1000+)
The Qs is how to pass Variable id's in Sp.??? need help.**

Comment: Not clear. Are you updating and inserting the results of the select? And given the rest of the question should INSERT INTO B  be INSERT INTO C?

Comment: thats insert into c